# Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit and Tomcat 5

Tags: tomcat5.5

Do I need a specific Tomcat 64-bit version to run on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit?
Or will the regular Tomcat 5 install exe work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need the 64-bit Java JDK only.  If Tomcat is written in Java then its cross platform and the Java distribution is where the platform dependence matters.

Comment: There are a few articles floating around about this. Apparently the 32-bit version of Tomcat cannot start the 64-bit JDK.  Tomcat 6 has 64 bit support.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running on Windows 2008 with 32 bit Tomcat 5 and 32 bit java with no issues, and no gotchas. To be more specific we are running a heavily used authentication module over the system so if it were problematic I would imagine we would know. We are running an instance of [Blackboard](http://www.blackboard.com) in conjunction with 64 bit JDK however and they utilize a tomcat web server, so I would think this would work as well for greater scalability, although there may be some additional tweaking needed to make this work.

Comment: yeah, in my experience the only reason you need the 64-bit jvm+tomcat  is if your JVM is having trouble and getting maxed out around 1.3GB of ram or so...  then you need the 64-bit JVM to go past that ram limit.